# Shape (line) under a tab element CSS

Tags: html, css, material-design

I'm a beginner in CSS but I'm currently trying to create a material-design header with "line" under each tab like on this Google site : [Our Products | Google](https://www.google.com/intl/en/about/products/)

If possible I'd also like the animation when changing tab.

For now my header html is :

```
<header>
  [MY LOGO]
  <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="" class="current-nav">tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

And my CSS :

```
header {
    display: table;
    background:#FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    width:100vw;
    clear: both;
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

nav {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5vw;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    margin 0;
    padding: 0;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 3vw;
}
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:visited {
    color: inherit;
}
nav a:hover,:active,:focus {
    color: #b82525;
}
```

How do I position the shape to be under the .current-nav tab ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the example you have linked to, you will see that one way they do this is by adding a border-bottom to the selected element. You can do this like so

```
.current-nav { 
    border-bottom:1px solid #4285f4;
}
```

They have another technique which is to add an element below, but i'll leave that for you to investigate/reverse engineer.

Comment: Thanks
As far as I understood, javascript is being used to change the absolute-defined position of an indepent element.
I plan to use Polymer and its web elements.

Answer (score 0):

just use `nav ul li a.current-nav{ border-bottom: 1px solid red; }` and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<header>
  [MY LOGO]
  <nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" class="current-nav">tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="line-selected right" style="display: block; left: 322px; right: 0.078px;"></div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

The left and right values depends on the sizes of your Logo and of your `<li>`. You have to change the style of the `"line-selected right"`class for each event.